# Returns TypeError: 'LinearRegression' object is not callable. Other answers with this error say LinearRegression has not been initialized

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I have looked up questions with similar errors and thought I had followed the steps to initialize LinearRegression with the lines

```
linreg_mean_dif = LinearRegression().fit(X_train_dif, y_train_dif)
```

and

```
linreg_lag1 = LinearRegression().fit(X_train_lag1, y_train_lag1)
```

however, I am still being told LinearRegression is not callable. What seems to be the problem with my code?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.stats import binom
import timeit
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser as datetime_parser
from dateutil.tz import tzutc,gettz
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tree_model as tree
```

Code here that imports data from tree_model and constructs the reversion_df dataframe

```
X_var1 = reversion_df['Difference from Mean'].values
y_var1 = reversion_df['Daily % Change'].values
X_var2 = reversion_df['Daily % Change Lag 1'][:len(reversion_df['Daily % Change Lag 1'])-1].values
y_var2 = reversion_df['Daily % Change'][:len(reversion_df['Daily % Change Lag 1'])-1].values

X_train_dif, X_test_dif, y_train_dif, y_test_dif = train_test_split(X_var1, y_var1, random_state = 0)
X_train_lag1, X_test_lag1, y_train_lag1, y_test_lag1 = train_test_split(X_var2, y_var2, random_state = 0)
X_train_dif = X_train_dif.reshape(-1, 1)
X_test_dif = X_test_dif.reshape(-1 , 1)
X_train_lag1 = X_train_lag1.reshape(-1, 1)
X_test_lag1 = X_test_lag1.reshape(-1 , 1)

linreg_mean_dif = LinearRegression().fit(X_train_dif, y_train_dif)
linreg_lag1 = LinearRegression().fit(X_train_lag1, y_train_lag1)

scores_train = (linreg_mean_dif.score(X_train_dif, y_train_dif), linreg_lag1(X_train_lag1, y_train_lag1))


print(scores_train)
```

Comment: Are there any other variables or modules\files named LinearRegression?  You can call `print(dir(LinearRegression))` and see if the method list makes sense.

Comment: Could you add the full error stacktrace? It is the most valuable info that Python gives, yet most questions here do not include it...

Answer (score 2):

You left a typo in the last line (right before the final `print`), where you wrote  `linreg_lag1(X_train_lag1, y_train_lag1)`. Replacing it with `linreg_lag1.score(X_train_lag1, y_train_lag1)` (which is probably what you meant) you should be fine

Comment: Man I feel stupid. Thanks so much, I spent quite a few hours trying to figure out what was wrong with this yesterday and could not, for the life of me solve it. Your answer was exactly what was wrong, thanks again!